# Unable to retrieve array values

Tags: php, arrays

I have a HTML form where I will be sending all the information to the server side. One of my field is like

```
<option value="bus_info[{$k->bus_id},{$k->route_from},{$k->route_to}]">{$k->route_from} To {$k->route_to},{$k->bus_time}</option>
```

And when check in PHP side

```
$bus_information[] = $_REQUEST['bid'];

var_dump($bus_information);`
```

it shows the following result :

```
array
  0 => string 'bus_info[1,Guwahati,Amguri]' (length=27)
```

Now how can I retrieve the elements from the array ? I tried `echo $bus_information[0][0];` but it shows the result `b` ! Why so

Comment: The value passed via `$_REQUEST['bid']` is just a string, not an array as you expect it to be (well it is an array of characters, which is why `$bus_information[0][0]` returns `b` but that is not relevant at this point). You need to parse the data to extract the comma separated values.

Comment: Because what you have is not an array, it's a *string* that vaguely looks like an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multidimensional arrays don't work that way in HTML and PHP. You should use this in your form:

```
<option value="bus_info[{$k->bus_id}][{$k->route_from}][{$k->route_to}]">{$k->route_from} To {$k->route_to},{$k->bus_time}</option>
```

EDIT based on comment:

Sorry, this will not work at all. I'm assuming you want the user to select some sort of route, and based on that you want to pass a particular value. The way a `<select>` works is this:

In your HTML use this:

```
<select name="test">
    <option value="1">First option</option>
    <option value="2">Second option</option>
</select>
```

Now, in PHP you can access the value that was submitted like this:

```
$_REQUEST['test'] //this value will be 1 if the user 
                  //selected the first option, or 2 if 
                  //he selected the second
```

You can use Arrays in the names of the input fields, so it would be possible to do something like this in HTML:

```
<select name="test[1]">
    <option value="1">First option</option>
    <option value="2">Second option</option>
</select>
<select name="test[2]">
    <option value="1">First option</option>
    <option value="2">Second option</option>
</select>
```

Note that I used the array notation on the `name` attribute, not the value. Now you can do this in PHP:

```
$_REQUEST['test'][1] //this value will be 1 if the user 
                     //selected the first option, or 2 if 
                     //he selected the second in the first
                     //drop down
$_REQUEST['test'][2] //this value will be 1 if the user 
                     //selected the first option, or 2 if 
                     //he selected the second in the second
                     //drop down
```

So what you're doing, using arrays in the `value` attribute will not work. You could do something like this:

```
<select name="bus_info">
    <option value="{$k->bus_id},{$k->route_from},{$k->route_to}">{$k->route_from} To {$k->route_to},{$k->bus_time}</option>
</select>
```

And then in PHP:

```
$values = explode($_REQUEST['bus_info']);
//now $values is an array with 3 elements, the ID, the route_from and route_to
```

Comment: Thanks . But when I `var_dump($_REQUEST['bus_info']);` , it shows `null` !

Answer (score 1):

`$_REQUEST['bid']` is just a string, not an array.

You can use some of php's string functions to convert it to an array though:

```
$result = $_REQUEST['bid'];
$result = strstr($result, '[');
$result = trim($result, '[]');
$array = explode(',' $result);
```

But personally I would have numerical values that map to my data on the server-end.

Answer (score 1):

**This will give you an array of values you're looking for:**

Remove the array wrapper in the option value field:

```
<option value="{$k->bus_id},{$k->route_from},{$k->route_to}">{$k->route_from} To {$k->route_to},{$k->bus_time}</option>
```

You will now get a string to work with when the form is submitted:

```
$bus_info_string = $_REQUEST['bid']; 

echo($bus_info_string);
```

The string looks like:

```
'1,Guwahati,Amguri'
```

#### Explode the string

Now use PHP's [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) method. This converts the string values into an array:

```
$bus_info_array = explode(",", $bus_info_string);
```

The array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 'Guwahati'
    [2] => 'Amguri'
)
```

### Now to access the individual elements, simply use:

```
echo $bus_info_array[0]; // Bus Id
echo $bus_info_array[1]; // Route From
echo $bus_info_array[2]; // Route To
```

Answer (score 0):

As the `var_dump()` is telling you, you hava string and not an array, means you need to use regex or split the string e.g. like:

Only print the content inside `[]` like:

```
<option value="{$k->bus_id},{$k->route_from},{$k->route_to}">{$k->route_from} To {$k->route_to},{$k->bus_time}</option>
```

Then you can get the array by the following:

```
$parts = explode(',', $bus_information);
```